# Context Managers in Matlab: Invoking __enter__ in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, exit, enter, contextmanager

I have a python package and I would like to use its classes and methods in Matlab. I know that this can be done directly since Matlab 2014b. I mean all you have to do is add `py.` in the beginning of your statements. So far so good, however, I couldn't figure out how to deal with **context managers** through MATLAB, which are invoked using the `with` statement. For instance, assume that we have the following class in a module called app.py,

```
class App(object):

    def __init__(self, input):
        self._input = input
        self._is_open = False

    def __enter__(self):
        self._is_open = True
        # many other stuff going after this but not relevant to this problem
```

In Matlab, I can call this as

```
app = py.app.App(input);
py.getattr(app, '_is_open')

ans =

logical

0
```

and I see an instance of App in my workspace. However, as expected only `__init__` is invoked this way but not `__enter__`.

So, is there a way to invoke `__enter__` from Matlab, as if we are calling it like `with App(input) as app:` in Python?

Note: I am using Python 3.5.1 and Matlab 2017b

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is any way to invoke the `__enter__` method of a Python class from MATLAB, but the `__exit__` method *might* be implicitly called (I'll address this further below).

It's important to first consider the purpose of [context managers](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) (via the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods), which is to provide a way to allocate and release resources in a scope-limited fashion, whether or not that scope is exited normally or via an error. MATLAB has a more limited means of "scoping": each function has its own [workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html), and control structures like loops, conditional statements, etc. within that function all share that workspace (unlike many languages in which these control structures have their own sub-scopes).

When a workspace is exited in MATLAB, the variables it contains are cleared, but any resources that were allocated may still need to be released. This can be achieved with [`onCleanup`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) objects. When they are cleared from memory, they invoke a given function for managing existing resources. An [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cleaning-up-when-the-function-completes.html#brrlvzw) would be opening and reading from a file:

```matlab
function openFileSafely(fileName)
  fid = fopen(fileName, 'r');
  c = onCleanup(@() fclose(fid));

  s = fread(fid);
  ...
end
```

Here, a file is opened and subsequently read from. An `onCleanup` object `c` is created that will close the file when `c` is cleared from memory upon exit from the function. If the file were simply closed with `fclose(fid)` at the end of the function, then an error exit from the function (such as during the course of reading data) would cause the file to still remain opened. Using an `onCleanup` object ensures that the file will be closed regardless of how the function exits. Here's an example of how this could be handled in Python:

```py
with open('some_file', 'w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write('Hola!')
```

Since MATLAB has a different means of "context management" than Python, this may explain why it's not possible to access the `__enter__` method. I tried with a class I knew had one: the [`io.FileIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.FileIO) class. I first looked for help:

```matlab
>> py.help('io.FileIO.__enter__')
Help on method_descriptor in io.FileIO:

io.FileIO.__enter__ = __enter__(...)
```

It finds some help text. It's not particularly *helpful*, but it's there. However, when I create an object and look at its [methods list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methods.html), neither `__enter__` nor `__exit__` (nor a clear equivalent) is there:

```matlab
>> fio = py.io.FileIO('test.txt');
>> methods(fio)

Methods for class py._io.FileIO:

FileIO      eq          ge          le          read        readinto    seek        truncate    writelines  
char        fileno      gt          lt          readable    readline    seekable    writable    
close       flush       isatty      ne          readall     readlines   tell        write       

Methods of py._io.FileIO inherited from handle.

Methods for class handle:

addlistener  eq           findprop     gt           le           ne           
delete       findobj      ge           isvalid      lt           notify
```

I did notice something interesting when I cleared the `fio` object, though. While the `fio` object still existed (with the file open), I couldn't delete or move the file, as expected. However, after issuing the command `clear fio`, *without first closing the file*, I was able to interact with the file normally. This implies that the file was automatically closed. This makes me wonder if the  `__exit__` method might be getting implicitly invoked, but I have yet to determine it for certain.