# Can I call tf.variable_scope without a "with" statement?

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

I want to call tensorflow's python APIs in matlab (see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-python-from-matlab.html).
The matlab does not support the "with" statement.
I can not create a tf.variable_scope without a "with" statement.
I have tried the two codes below, but both do not work.
Is there any solution?

Python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.variable_scope('123') as vs:
    print(vs.name)  # OK
vs2 = tf.variable_scope('456')
print(vs2.name)  # AttributeError: 'variable_scope' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Matlab:

```
vs = py.tensorflow.variable_scope('GRAPH', pyargs('reuse', py.tensorflow.AUTO_REUSE));
vs.name  % No appropriate method, property, or field 'name' for class 'py.tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope.variable_scope'.
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192413/context-managers-in-matlab-invoking-enter-in-matlab?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Delete `print(vs2.name)`, try `print(vs2.__enter__().name)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the python context like

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope('123') as vs:
    print(vs.name)  # OK


vs2_obj = tf.variable_scope('456')
vs2 = vs2_obj.__enter__()
try:
    print(vs2.name)  # OK as well
finally:
    vs2_obj.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

But I guess there are some site-effects.

Explanation: There is a difference between a context-object `vs2_obj` and the current context `vs2` itself.

This gives the output

```
123
456
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I write a tool class to mimic "with" statements in matlab.

helper.py:

```
class With(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj
        self._p = self._obj.__enter__()

    def __del__(self):
        self._obj.__exit__(None, None, None)

    def get(self):
        return self._p
```

Matlab:

```
with_vs = py.helper.With(py.tensorflow.variable_scope('X'));
with_vs.get().name
...
clear with_vs;
```